# How do I create working environment for development in php?

Tags: c#, php

What various softwares will I need to develop php web site? and what technologies will I need to learn? I have some knowledge of c#, asp.net, Sql server and java-scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neccessary:

- An editor or IDE you like. This can be emacs/vim, notepad/notepad++, textMate, Eclipse, Netbeans, whatever floats your boat.
- A server to run your site obviously, also for testen. This can be a LAMP (linux apache Mysql PHP) stack, or an other stack like WAMP, XAMP etc. These are for windows, linux and mac available. You can obviously install the separate webserver and php support yourself.

possibly

- A debug environment, possibly one that connects with your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop php website, you obviosly need knowledge of PHP :) You should have knowledge of databases such as mySQL. Also, HTML, CSS and Javascript will be used.
See this page, I think it will be helpful to get started: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php
Also you can find lots of tutorials on google. Few other helpful links are: 
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/
and http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/

Answer (score 1):

You obviously need to learn PHP. You need a PHP-serving web server, an [*AMP package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMP_packages) being a popular choice. To edit PHP files, you need a text editor. To make websites, you need to know HTML. To make *dynamic* websites, you need Javascript. You likely need to know how to use SQL databases, but there are many ways to store data. That's it (for the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

To develop any website you require the subject knowledge but to make it perfect you need to know the things like how to represent, users friendly UI, page ranking concepts etc......

to develop a website you can use different domains but my suggestion is php, because it runs in linux OS also.

If you select PHP, first find which framework ( codeigniter, zend framework etc...) you can use.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a framework in order to make a php website, and starting off with it might not be the best choice if you want to learn the basics; also, codeigniter and zend framework are really far each from the other, they're not an equivalent choice. And PHP is NOT A DOMAIN!!!